# argument of type 'any ' is not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript-typings

I am new to TypeScript and I am trying following

```
 const storedNumber = [1,2,3,4,5];
 Math.max(storedNumber)
```

but I kept typescript error saying

> argument of type 'any ' is not assignable to parameter of type number

Comment: Read the documentation on [`Math.max([value1[, value2[, ...]]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: `Math.max` doesn't accept an array. It accepts discrete values. If you need to get the max of an array, use `var result = Math.max.apply(Math, theArray)` or on modern JavaScript environments `var result = Math.max(...theArray);`.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.max` requires numbers as arguments like `Math.max(1, 3, 2)` not an array. You can `spread` the array.

```js
const storedNumber = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(  Math.max(...storedNumber) );
```

Doc: [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)